# Create a link that facebook recognise

Tags: php, facebook, audio

I have a question and i don't know how to explain.
   If i post an audio file on soundcloud (e.g.) the site is giving me a link. Facebook recognizes the link and is showing me a play button, and i can listen directly on the page, without having to go to the soundcloud. Also, is on soundcloud i upload an image, facebook will show my image.
     Can someone explain how can i do that ?

I have a server and from time to time i want to post some audio file (link from my server) to facebook. I want facebook to recognize my links, so everyone who is accessing my page to be able to listen the audio file.

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something called [Open Graphs Tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/). This is meta data which lives in header of your page.